# Float formatting with f-string using a class attribute as parameter

Tags: python-3.x, string-formatting, f-string

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
class P():
    def __init__(self):
        self.digits = 5
        self.pi = f"{np.pi:eval(self.digits)f}"

test = Test()
test.pi
```

I know that `f"{np.pi:5.f}"` works, but is it possible to do it with the attribute of a class? Like in a dynamic way? It doesn't needs to  use `eval()`, the importat part is if `self.digits` can be used in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can nest formats inside the format specifier

taking your example and fixing a few things (missing imports, unnecessary `numpy`, class name mismatch, print the variable instead of just accessing it, dot in front of the number so it limits the decimal places):

```py
import math

class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.digits = 5
        self.pi = f"{math.pi:.{self.digits}f}"

test = Test()
print(test.pi)
```

the output:

```
$ python3 t.py 
3.14159
```

Comment: Thank you @Anthony Sottile, this was what I was looking for :)